# Azure AppGW, Containers and MS Datacenter Maintenance?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-application-gateway

I’m hoping you can provide some quick guidance to use on AppGw’s (setup as simple load balancers), Containers, and Azure datacenter host maintenance.

We recently launched a project built by a partner / vendor group for us. This application uses containers behind an Appgw (it doesnt have a WAF, its only for HA – we’ve been calling this an ILB).

AppGW/ILB --> Container Group of 2 containers

The ILB has backend targets to containers using IP addresses. We have noticed some unmanaged by us container restarts that involve the container grabbing a new IP address. One that is NOT mapped to the ILB.

This of course is bad, as the container has now ‘wandered off' the ILB, and the container is now 'out of service' even though it is up and running.

Upon further research, we found this limitation bullet from Microsoft (third bullet in the limitations section)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-update#limitations

> “The IP address of a container group is typically retained between
> updates, but isn't guaranteed to remain the same. As long as the
> container group is deployed to the same underlying host, the container
> group retains its IP address. Although rare, there are some
> Azure-internal events that can cause redeployment to a different host.
> To mitigate this issue, we recommend using a DNS name label for your
> container instances.”

I see there is an azure CLI command to do this:

```
az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myalpine --image alpine:latest --ports 80 443 --dns-name-label contoso
```

I am assuming we then create an A record in DNS and we then use that name in the ILB backend target reference.

However, am I missing something? (I think I am not understanding this)

The issue here is that the containers are changing IP. A DNS A record will become invalid in one of these IP Address changed due to MS datacenter change event / container host move situations.

(i.e., I see using a dns record as the same as using the IP address in the ILB)

I must be missing something here.

Can someone connect up the dots I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there other documentation I am missing?